# which one is more effective /powerful writing the mantra or chanting the mantra?

Tags: mantras

which one is more effective /powerful  writing the mantra  or chanting the mantra ?

It is not possible to write mantra all times  ,by writing mantra our hands getting  pain also

I have read some  swami sivananda books . Mantra writing suggested in his books

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Traditionally Mantra is recited and not written down. Likhita Japa is not mentioned in scriptures to my knowledge. But some modern day Gurus/saints do mention about the method's usefulness.

So, from scriptures, we can not know which method is the more efficient one.

Swami Sivananda, in his book ["Japa Yoga - A COMPREHENSIVE TREATISE ON MANTRA-SASTRA"](http://japa-yoga.org/japa.pdf), however mentions that writing down Mantras is very efficient among all the methods that we have:

> **14. Likhita Japa**
>
> Write down daily in a notebook your Ishta Mantra or Guru-Mantra, for
> half an hour. When you write the Mantra, observe Mouna. Write the
> Mantra clearly in ink. On Sundays and holidays, write this for one
> hour. In a common place collect your friends also and let them write
> the Mantras. This is Likhita Japa. you can develop a wonderful power
> of concentration. Prescribe this to all of your family-members.
> Incalculable spiritual benefits are derived from Likhita Japa
> (Mantra-writing).  **Of the various methods of Japa described in the
> scriptures, viz., Vaikhari, Upamsu and Manasika, etc., Likhita Japa is
> very efficacious. It helps the Sadhaka in concentration of the mind
> and gradually leads to meditation.**  An aspirant should select the
> Mantra of his tutelary deity, or Ishta, according to his liking or
> inclination. Repetition of the same Mantra with meaning and Bhava
> should be practised both orally and in writing. For oral Japa, the
> help of a Maala or rosary is required. For Likhita Japa a notebook and
> a pen should be used. In Mantra-writing there is no restriction about
> any particular script. It may be written in any language. The
> following rules may be observed while practising Mantra-writing:-
>
> 1. Regularity and punctuality of time should be observed. This would itself bring the requisite help and be of the utmost benefit to the
>    Sadhaka.
> 2. Physical and mental purity should be observed. Before sitting for Mantra-writing, the face, hand and feet should be washed. Effort
>    should be made to keep the mind pure during Mantra-writing. Drive out
>    all worldly thoughts while writing Mantra.
> 3. Continue to sit in one pose as long as possible. Frequent change of a pose or Asana should be avoided. Sitting in one Asana would increase
>    your power of endureance and also considerable energy will be
>    preserved.

.............

> The notebook should be well kept and treated with respect and purity.
> When completed, it should be stocked in a box and kept in your
> meditation room in front of the Lord's picture. The very presence of
> these Mantranotebooks will create favourable vibrations requisite for
> your Sadhana.  The benefits of Mantra-writing or Likhita Japa cannot
> be adequately described. Besides bringing about purity of heart and
> concentration of mind, Mantra-writing givesyou control of Asana,
> control of Indriyas, particularly the sight and the tongue, and fills
> you with the power of endurance. You attain peace of mind quickly. You
> approach nearer to God through MantraSakti. These benefits can be
> experienced only through regular and incessant practice of Likhita
> Japa. Those who are not conversant with this Yoga should start the
> practice immediately and even if they take to this practice for half
> an hour daily, they will realise its benefits within six months.

*(quotes are from page 87 onward of the PDF)*

But, I don't think that we can prove this assertion from scriptures. That Likhita Japa is more efficient than the traditional method of chanting.